# Custom jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

My boss asked me to program a custom jQuery validation plugin. If `<input />` tag  has special attribute `[needcheck]`, my plugin must determine the type of `[needcheck]` and  check input data before submit.

For example:

```
<input name="email" type="text" needchek=”Email”/>
```

If value of `<input />` tag has errors, plugin must show a promting message.

Available types for `[needcheck]`:

- `Date:[FORMATDATE]` – date in format (For example `Date:dd.MM.yyyy`)
- `Time:[TIMEFORMAT]` – time in format (for example `Time:HH:MM:SS`)
- `INT` – integer  number
- `Decimal:[DECIMALFORMAT]` – Decimal number
- `Email` – email address
- Etc.

The code:

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.somePlugin = function(options) { 
        var defaults = { 
            someOption: 'someValue'
        }; 
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options); 
    };   
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: 1st: What exactly is your question and 2nd: you might get in trouble generating valid HTML/XHTML/XML with a non standards compliant tag.

Comment: 1. How can I realize jquery plugin using code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [jQuery plugin validity](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/)  as it is flexible enough for almost anything, because you can give it an assert or callback as a validation rule: [Assert Demo](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm#Assert)

Comment: Great alternative, that plugin is pretty cool, and let's you do virtualy everything